# Azure databricks cluster init script using workspace path: Init script failure: RESOURCE DOES NOT EXIST

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

I am trying to add a simple init script to my Azure databricks cluster. The script path is like `/Workspace/Shared/my-cluster-init.sh`. When I tried to start the cluster with the init script, I am seeing the following error:

> Init script failure: RESOURCE DOES NOT EXIST: No file found at /Workspace/Shared/cluster-init.sh

Which is confusing, because the file does exist. I have tried with different access mode (`Single user`, `shared`, `No isolation shared`), and they all fail with the same error.

My databricks runtime version: 10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `/Workspace` part, just leave `/Shared/my-cluster-init.sh` - as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/init-scripts/cluster-scoped#configure-a-cluster-scoped-init-script-using-the-ui):

> For an init script stored in your home directory with workspace files: `/Users/<user-name>/<script-name>.sh`.